# Grub is not booting detected OS's marked with "rolling"

Tags: linux, bios, multi-boot, fedora, grub

I have a disk with Windows 10 installed, and another one with several patitions, each of them with a Linux distro installed: fedora, Ubuntu, Kali and EndeavourOS.
However the OS's marked with the word *rolling* are not booting.
Here is the log given by Fedora when updating grub:

```
...# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found Windows 10 on /dev/sdb1
Found Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (20.04) on /dev/sdc5
Found Kali GNU/Linux Rolling on /dev/sdc6
Found EndeavourOS Linux (rolling) on /dev/sdc8
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

What does *rolling* mean in this context?
How can I fix this problem?

Thanks beforehand for the help

Note: my system uses BIOS (not UEFI)

Comment: What happens when it doesn't boot?  Is there an error message?

Comment: The booting process crashes "kernel panic not syncing vfs unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (0,0)"